# How do I remove this outline?

Tags: html, css, safari

In Safari when clicking on these buttons I get this blue outline. How can I remove it?

[image]

I tried `a {outline: none;}` but it does not work.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: please provide a demo or live link

Comment: Provide Some More Html Css to understand the issue.

Comment: Try `a:focus { outline:none; }`

Comment: It could be a border, or a psudo element. Try ` a {border: unset!important;}`, and `a:before, a:after {opacity: 0!important};`.

Comment: Have you tried `a { border: none; }`, or even better you can use HTML Reset

Answer (score 0):

I have taken one example from w3school similar to yours this when I click on the button it looks similar to your button like below

[image]

To remove this outline you have to do below

1. Inspect the browser developer tools.
2. Please right-click on your button and select inspect to get select your element in the DOM.
3. And select the below steps from the Image in sequence.

[image]

Then unselect this class below in the Image to remove the outline

[image]

and Then also problem not solve then please show image of you inspect DOM options

Comment: That's not a direct answer.